# forge.topbar.setTitleImage(URL,success,error); dynamic image .. fileCache?

Tags: trigger.io

I have been told this is possible to do but cannot get this to work.

Basically I am trying to cache and image using forge.file.cacheURL()

Now I can get the file just fine and display it in the page by creating a new Image object but what I want to do is use this cached image to change the image in the topbar.

When ever I try to do it I get an error saying "file not found" and after reading the docs a little more it seems that trigger may have "src/" coded into the class because if I put just "image/logo.png" the logo.png will show up in the header because its part of the app package.

I guess the question is.. Is my assumption correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone is interested in this, the ability was added a while ago to the API so you can now use a cached image or filesaveURL feature of forge to change the header image dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The native UI elements (topbar/tabbar) load images directly from your apps package, not through a URL in the same ways images are shown in the webview.

What this means is that currently you can only use images included in your app in the topbar/tabbar modules.

Comment: That is what I was starting to think but I had been told this by trigger.io support and had sent them some code (still waiting on that)

Is there a way to download and store an image in the package and use that or possibly create a new image object on the fly and display it?